# Way to concat strings when using binding in Silverlight

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight

I wonder if there is a way of concating two strings in Silverlight inside xaml file. I have a DataGrid where one of the columns is 'Default Contact' and I would like to represent data in there as first and last name.

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Default Contact"
                        Binding="{Binding Path=DefaultContact.FirstName}" />
```

I was thinking about something like:

```
Binding="{Binding Path=DefaultContact.FirstName + " " + DefaultContact.LasttName}"
```

But this doesn't work. I don't even know if this is possible to achieve. Seems like really basic thing so I hope it is supported in some way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a DataGridTemplateColumn and have both your first and last name in the template. Something like this:

```
 <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0"
                            Text="{Binding DefaultContact.FirstName}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DefaultContact.LastName}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
 </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. create a field in `DefaultContact`
   called DisplayName and concatenate
   there
2. Create `ValueConverter` (check MSDN)